# Как хранить часовой пояс в конфигурации?

Tags: php, ооп

В основной конфигурации приложения я решил хранить часовой пояс в виде объекта DateTimeZone:

```
class Options
{
    $private $dateTimeZone;

    public function setDateTimeZone(\DateTimeZone $timezone) : void
    {
        $this->dateTimeZone = $timezone;
    }

    public function getDateTimeZone() : object
    {
        return clone($this->dateTimeZone);
    }

}
```

Если в getDateTimeZone() отдавать не клон объекта, а ссылку на него `return $this->dateTimeZone;` то в случае любого изменения часового пояса в клиентском коде часовой пояс изменится и в конфигурации. Насколько оправданно решение с клонированием? Может лучше хранить часовой пояс в виде строки (к примеру: $this->dateTimeZone='UTC')?